# TextureLoader fail to load cross-origin image

Tags: javascript, three.js

I fail to load image in chrome by TextureLoader

I want to load the image from the URL that is "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Engels.jpg?width=300",but I get error that is "Access to image at 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Engels.jpg?width=300' (redirected from 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Engels.jpg?width=300') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."(I set loader.crossOrigin anonymous).if I set loader.crossOrigin undefined,loader can load the image but can't be rendered with error"THREE.WebGLState: TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided."

Answer (score 1):

Servers at `https://commons.wikimedia.org` have not implemented `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers, so you may not be able to fetch the image directly.

You can save the image to your local file system and reference it, that would work for sure.

Comment: Why loader can load the image if i set crossOrigin undefined (but WebGL can't render it)

Comment: Because `crossOrigin` is only a request to `commons.wikimedia.org` for permission to use the image. It's up to them and their servers to grant that permission.

Comment: I change the url to 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Engels.jpg' and now my textureloader can load the image when the crossOrigin is anonymous .But WebGL still can not render the image with the error ""THREE.WebGLState: TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.""

Comment: I'm not sure what significant advantage you gain by adding images through remote urls and worrying about related errors, instead of simply including them through your ocal file system.